# want to dynamically print letters after a given interval of time, Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!(…)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var str = "get_data_httpaja.php?un=" + $scope.uName;
var avail=["a","v","a","i","l","a","b","l","e"];
var i=0;
$http.get(str).then(function (dt) {
    alert(dt.data);
    //     $scope.uPlace = dt.data;
    if(dt.data==0){
        var myvar=$window.setInterval(function () {
            $scope.$watch("uAvailable",function (nv,ov) {
                $scope.uAvailable+=avail[i];
            })
            i++;                     
        },500)
        if(i>8)$window.clearInterval(myvar);
    }
}
```

I am fetching a result from server, after that if `result==0` then I want to print "Available" dynamically letter by letter, but getting errors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope,$timeout,$interval) {
    $scope.uAvailable = '';
    $timeout(function(){},500).then(function () {
        var avail=["a","v","a","i","l","a","b","l","e"];
        $interval(function(counter){
            $scope.uAvailable += avail[--counter];            
        }, 500, avail.length);
    });
}
```

I've used $timeout instead of $http because both return Promise (it's just for this example purpose).

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/obkx9zaz/

Comment: What do you mean by events?